# How to write text to a file on external storage on android?

Tags: java, android

Writing some text to a file on an android device seems to be a major endeavor. Starting from [an answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android) I have implemented the following code into my single 'Hello-World' activity:

```
try {
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(this.openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
    outputStreamWriter.write("lalala");
    outputStreamWriter.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
}
```

which does not throw an exception, but seems to work. But is there a way to 'see' the file created with the `File Manager` on android? The code snippet seems to write to a 'secret' location on the android file system related to the application itself (governed by using `this.openFileOutput`).

Consulting different google-links ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779256/how-do-i-write-to-a-txt-file-in-android)  [and this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625837/android-what-is-wrong-with-openfileoutput)) I come up with the following code:

```
File file = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir("temp"), "testfile.txt");
FileOutputStream fileOutput = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
fileOutput.write("lalala");
fileOutput.close();
```

which throws an error

```
Error:(55, 19) error: no suitable method found for write(String) method FileOutputStream.write(int) is not applicable (actual argument String cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion) method FileOutputStream.write(byte[],int,int) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) method OutputStream.write(int) is not applicable (actual argument String cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion) method OutputStream.write(byte[],int,int) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) method OutputStream.write(byte[]) is not applicable (actual argument String cannot be converted to byte[] by method invocation conversion)
```

So how to do this right?

As a side note: This is for debugging/educational purposes only and not intended to be part of a final app!

To be clear: I want to create a file inside the `temp` directory I can see with a FileManager (the `temp` directory is on the same level as `My Documents`
, `Music`, `DCIM`, `Download` and the like...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But is there a way to 'see' the file created with the File Manager on android?

I am not certain what "the File Manager" is that you are referring to, as Android does not really have one. However, you are writing to an app's [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), and that is private to the app. It cannot be viewed by other apps or ordinary users, except on rooted devices and via some cumbersome Android SDK tools.

> So how to do this right?

```
File file = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "testfile.txt");
FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutput);
outputStreamWriter.write("lalala");
outputStreamWriter.flush();
fileOutput.getFD().sync();
outputStreamWriter.close();
```

Also:

- Please do this work on a background thread
- On Android 4.3 (API Level 18) and older devices, you need to hold the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to work with [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html)

If you also want to have this file show up quickly in on-device or on-development-machine file managers, use this after closing the file:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
  this,
  new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()},
  null,
  null);
```

(where `this` is some `Context`, such as an `Activity` or `Service`)

Comment: What is the unused variable `outputStreamWriter` used for?

Comment: @Alex: Whoops, sorry -- that was for the `write()` call. I have fixed my answer.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks. Could you explain what the differences are between `File`, `FileOutputStream` and `OutputStreamWriter`? I am only familiar with several programming language which usually have a single entity named `File` or something to write something to a file. Why does android use these three entities instead? What is the reason for that complication?

Comment: @Alex: "Why does android use these three entities instead?" -- Android doesn't. Java does. As for "why did developer X do thing Y that I disagree with?", Stack Overflow is not well-suited for such questions. The only person who usually can answer that definitively is developer X, who is unlikely to be helping here. I can tell you that files being separate from streams is a common concept in programming languages, because streams do not have to relate to files (e.g., streams for data exchanged over sockets).

Comment: Anyway, your code does not really seem to work. When I check on my device in the `temp` directory, I do not see a file named `testfile.txt`.

Comment: @Alex: Sorry, you had that there, and I copied it without thinking. `"temp"` is not a valid value. Use `null` or one of [the documented values](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Still does not seem to work. I tried `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` and `Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC`, but no file named `testfile.txt` was created in any of these directories...

Comment: @Alex: Where and how are you looking? `getExternalFilesDir()` will be in `Android/data/your.application.id.here/files/` in external storage, where `your.application.id.here` is your `applicationId` in `build.gradle` (or your `package` in `AndroidManifest.xml`). If you are using anything other than `adb shell` to look, you also need to use the `MediaScannerConnection` code that I mentioned, and possibly click "refresh" or "reload" in the file manager.

Comment: Ok, now I have it! Thanks. I need to write down that 'external files dir' is bound to the application in that very special app dir... Never seen it explained in any of these links I have linked...

Comment: @Alex: Presumably, you were previously looking in top-level directories in external storage. Standard ones (e.g., `DIRECTORY_MUSIC`) are obtained via `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`.